# Using loops to generate random graphs and adjacency matrix in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, matrix, graph

I am new to R and need some help with writing the correct code.

I want to generate Erdos Renyi random graphs and calculate the Clustering Coefficient for the graphs.

A random graph of this model will have n vertices (in my case, n =5). And the existence of an edge between 2 vertices is determined by probability p. I have a large csv file with multiple rows and columns, with one of the columns containing the probability values I want to use.

For each probability value, I want to program R to read it and generate 100 random graphs and get the adjacency matrix for the 100 random graphs.

I can get the adjacency matrix for 100 graphs using a specific probability value (p=0.39) with this code

```
 adjacency <- replicate(100,get.adjacency(erdos.renyi.game(5,0.39,type="gnp"),sparse = FALSE))
```

And I'm trying to find a way to get R to go through my csv file and use each row in the column named 'ProbabilityValue' as the probability value.

Here is what I have so far

```
for (i in 1:nrow(data)){
all.adjacency[i] <- 
replicate(100,get.adjacency(erdos.renyi.game(5,data[i,"ProbabilityValue"],type="gnp"), sparse = FALSE))
}
```

But I get a warning message saying "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length" and got all zeros as the output.

To get the clustering, I installed the `DirectedClustering` package that takes in an adjacency matrix and gives the clustering as the output. The function is called `ClustBCG()`.

I run this line of code with `adjacency` as an input to get the clustering

```
ClustBCG(adjacency,"undirected")
```

I got an error saying `adjacency` is not a valid matrix object. I know that having 'adjacency' as an input is incorrect, but I don't know of any other ways to input this.

For each probability value in the "ProbabilityValue" column, I would like to get the adjacency matrix of the 100 randomly generated graphs. And then read each of the 100 adjacency matrices into the function `ClustBCG()` to get 100 clustering values as the output. But I'm not sure where to begin. Could you please help me out or direct me to the appropriate functions to use in R?

(I apologise for asking a long question but I am so lost)

Any help is much appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't have `DirectedClust` available so I can't run your code.  But if `adjacency` is a list of matrix objects, then

```
library(tidyverse)
results <- map(adjacency, ~ ClustBCG(.x,"undirected")
```

should work.

Comment: I think the problem is the use of `replicate`, as it returns a matrix and not a list of matrices; so I think  `lapply` is better to generate the data

Comment: I think there is a typo in the question: the package name is ```DirectedClustering```. I am trying to edit, but am getting "Suggested edit queue is full". 
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DirectedClustering/DirectedClustering.pdf